# Using non-english characters breaks listings

Tags: listings, characters, html

**Problem:**

When using non-English characters, the listings package breaks in terms of creating a space in the line next to code numbers.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of colors
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.5, 1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.6, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of HTML5
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!-},
  keywords={}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Setup for listings
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstset{%
  % General design
  inputencoding=utf8,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\upshape,
  frame=l,
  comment=[l]{;},
  escapeinside={;@}{\^^M},
  escapeinside=`',
  % line-numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  % Code design
  identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorPink},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
  % Code
  language=html,
  alsodigit={.:},
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false,
  % German umlauts
  literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Check keywords within code
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\gdef\lst@BeginTag{%
    \lst@DelimOpen
        \lst@ifextags\else
        {\let\lst@ifkeywords\iftrue
         \lst@ifmarkfirstintag\lst@firstintagtrue\fi\color{editorBlue}}}
\gdef\lst@EndTag{\lst@DelimClose\lst@ifextags\else\color{editorBlue}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=1]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <title>Kod med indentering</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h1>Artiklar om frukt</h1>
      <article>
        <h2>Äpple</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Apelsin</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

Make sure that the break in code line does not occur.

Comment: You can add a bit more space between the lines with `lineskip=1pt,`, or use another font (lmodern seems to work) where the Ä is smaller.

Comment: I tried package `minted` instead.  I did not show that problem.  Although I must confess, that on the first try, it used colors, that are not identical with your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Using lineskip=1pt reformats everything which is not desired. Loading `lmodern` seems so far as a nice solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**LINESPACING**

On a lark, I tried changing the `literate` table to `{Ä}{{\smash{\"A}}}1` and it seems to work.  Don't know if it is kosher.

**COLOR**

On the issue of color of the diacritics, I tried a strategy of first extending the change to the literate table to read `{Ä}{{\smash{\color{\CLR}\"A}}}1` and then had to figure out how and where to save the color named `\CLR`.  Those changes included

```
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{...
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue}\gdef\CLR{editorPink},
...}
```

and

```
\lstset{...
  identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange}\gdef\CLR{editorOrange},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorPink}\gdef\CLR{editorPink},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray}\gdef\CLR{editorGray},
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple}\gdef\CLR{editorPurple},
...}
```

and

```
\gdef\lst@EndTag{\lst@DelimClose\lst@ifextags\else\color{editorBlue}%
                 \gdef\CLR{editorOrange}}
```

With those changes, and adding a "Ä" to lines 2, 5, 11, and 12 of the listing for test purposes, it seems to work, though I am no expert on `listings`.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of colors
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.5, 1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.6, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of HTML5
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue}\gdef\CLR{editorPink},
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!-},
  keywords={}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Setup for listings
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstset{%
  % General design
  inputencoding=utf8,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\upshape,
  frame=l,
  comment=[l]{;},
  escapeinside={;@}{\^^M},
  escapeinside=`',
  % line-numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  % Code design
  identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange}\gdef\CLR{editorOrange},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorPink}\gdef\CLR{editorPink},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray}\gdef\CLR{editorGray},
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple}\gdef\CLR{editorPurple},
  % Code
  language=html,
  alsodigit={.:},
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false,
  % German umlauts
  literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\smash{\color{\CLR}\"A}}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Check keywords within code
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\gdef\lst@BeginTag{%
    \lst@DelimOpen
        \lst@ifextags\else
        {\let\lst@ifkeywords\iftrue
         \lst@ifmarkfirstintag\lst@firstintagtrue\fi\color{editorBlue}}}
\gdef\lst@EndTag{\lst@DelimClose\lst@ifextags\else\color{editorBlue}%
                 \gdef\CLR{editorOrange}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=1]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="Äsv">
  <head>
    <title>Kod med indentering</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8Ä">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h1>Artiklar om frukt</h1>
      <article>
        <Äh2>Äpple</Äh2>
        <pÄ>TexÄt</pÄ>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Apelsin</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Copy/pasted your literate code and did a run. Same results, the gap is still there. Using pdfLaTex.

Comment: @kexxcream I am also using pdflatex, and since I don't fully understand the underlying mechanism, I'm not sure I can add more at this time, other than to say, on my system, the change made the difference.

Comment: I think, the black "Ä" also seems to be part of the problem?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks, appreciated. Yes, the Ä seems to be part of the problem.

Comment: @Jan Of course, `{Ä}{{\smash{\color{editorOrange}\"A}}}1` will fix this case, but only if umlauted capital A's only appear as identifiers, and not as keywords, comments, or strings.

Comment: @Jan Please see my edit.